# Angular 9 dynamically load form-components in router-outlet of parent-component (create/edit)

Tags: angular

Use Case: We have different forms for creating and editing a *mutation of a company* (e.g. AddressChange). So you can select the type of mutation (e.g. AddressChange) in a dropdown and then you will be redirected to the corresponding mutation form (e.g. AddresschangeForm).

I created a component for each form (AddressChange, CEOChange...) and two wrapper components (create and edit) with only the buttons (create, save...) that would send the mutation object to the server.

Now I can load the forms via the url into the `router-outlet` of the create-component/edit-component: 
`/mutations/create/AddressChanges` 
`/mutations/edit/CEOChange/123`

It seems that I cannot call the event emitters on the router outlet itself to trigger the wrapper component from the form component.

**create-component.html:**
`<router-outlet (mutationChanged)="mutationChanged($event)"></router-outlet>`

So I wonder if this is really the right way to handle this scenario or if it would be better to define all components in the create-component and edit-component and use ngIf to decide which one should be visible? I made an illustration to understand the use case.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first apporch is totally fine,

you should use a Service to handel communication between components,

perhaps a Subject and an Obserbable

Eg

```
import { map, shareReplay, filter, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class StateFacadeService {
  private someSubject = new Subject<any>();

  public someObs$ = this.someSubject.asObservable().pipe(shareReplay());

  constructor() {}

  public mutationChanged(mutation: any): void {
    this.someSubject.next(mutation);
  }
}
```

in each form component

```
  constructor(private state: StateFacadeService) {}

makeChanges(mutation: any): void {
  this.state.mutationChanged(mutation)
}
```

and in the partent component

```
  public changes$  = this.state.someObs$


  constructor(private state: StateFacadeService) {}


noOnInit(): void {

  // TODO handel unsubscribe

  this.changes$.subscribe((changes: ant): void => {
    /** DO Somthing Amazing */
  })
}
```